# Функция udf_StripHTML в sql заменяет некоторые буквы в тексте на вопросик(?)

Tags: c#, sql

Есть текст с html тегом и я пытаюсь из него извлеч строку используя `sql` функцию `udf_StripHTML`:

```
var htmlContent = "<b>Новости / Жаңалықтар </b>";
var content = DB.udf_StripHTML(htmlContent);
```

И функция `udf_StripHTML(text)` вернёт мне так:

```
Новости / Жа?алы?тар
```

заменяя некоторые буквы на `?` , как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Зачем вам DB для этого?

Comment: @aepot это же DataContext, подключение к базе данных

Comment: Как вы определили, что там реально знаки вопроса, не в консоль ли случаем вывели?

Comment: @aepot через Management Studio запустил скрипт select dbo.udf_StripHTML('<b>Новости / Жаңалықтар </b>')

Comment: Ну тогда убедитесь что Management Studio поддерживает UTF-8 кодировку, проблема у вас именно с тем, что данные символы не поддерживаются кодировкой. А почему бы HTML теги прямо в C# не вырезать? И записать в базу без них? Какую задачу вы решаете? И при чем здесь студия, если у вас `var content`. Я спросил, как вы определили, что в переменной `content` содержатся знаки вопроса?

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Comment: @aepot спасибо, оказывается там  в методе "udf_StripHTML" нужно было использовать NVARCHAR

Comment: Ерунду вы какую-то делаете. База данных - это механизмы, которые созданы в первую очередь для **хранения** данных, да, вы можете на них не знаю, игрушку простенькую написать, сделав уйму хранимых процедур и прочего, но это будет простой кусок бесполезного кода, который в разы будет уступать по эффективности специализированным под это языкам и их утилитам! Так что, получаете через C# нужные HTML данные, там их разбиваете, а всякие ваши `Новости / Жаңалықтар` записываете в базу (если надо это хранить), но не как иначе!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  согласен)) мне тоже не нравится это ерунда, кто-то из прогеров написал когда-то... наверно лучше поменяю это говно код xD

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что в `sql`функция `udf_StripHTML` принимала и возвращала `VARCHAR`.
Чтобы решить нужно поменять на `NVARCHAR`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] (@HTMLText NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@HTMLText, '&nbsp;', ' ')));
END
GO
```

таким образом метод правильно возвращает текст:

```
Новости / Жаңалықтар
```